# Divs stacking above each other in the wrong order

Tags: html, css

I have a main div with 2 divs inside it, and a secondary div. To get the divs inside the main to be in the poisition i wanted them to be i set position to relative and it worked but the secondary div is now above the main div(in the browser) for some reason. I probably used    position   wrong, if someone can correct my it will help me a lot.

```css
    #main {
      position: relative;
    }
    #right {
      float: right;
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    #left {
      float: left;
      position: relative;
      displayLinline-block;
    }
    #subDiv {
      position: relative;
    }
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="left">
  </div>
  <div id="right">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="subDiv">
</div>
```

browser shows:

```
<div id="subDiv">
</div>
<div id="main">
<div id="left">
</div>
<div id="right">
</div>
</div>
```

what's my mistake?

Comment: Your HTML doesn't look correct if you want the three floated next to eachother. You need to wrap all the divs in a parent container and clear it

Comment: I'm sorry, english isnt my native language so i had trouble explaining myself properly. still, thanks for all the help, and also i want to say that the downvotes are very not nice. I'm just a kid trying to learn how to build a website and because my questions are too easy or stupid or i dont know what its not fair and also later i cant ask more questions that will help me learn more and get better which i think that is the purpose of this website. Please be thoughtful when down voting a post. thanks for all the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap a clearfix around the 2 floating divs. Also, display inline-block is used instead of floating, not in additon too. You also have a typo in your css "displayLinline-block;" but that could just be your example.

You can make a new class like such:

```
.cf:after { visibility:hidden; display:block; content:"" ; clear:both; height:0px;}
```

and then wrap all your floated elements in a classed called "cf" and this will fix your issue.

```
<div class="cf">
<div class="fleft"> this is a div floating left </div>
<div class="fright"> this is a div floating right </div>
</div> <!-- //clearfix -->

<div> another div with more content that is not interferred with content above. </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what look you are trying to achieve but it *sounds* as though you need to clear the floats.

There are multiple methods of clearing which are detailed in [**THIS**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-clearfix) Stack Overflow question

```css
#left,
#right,
#subDiv {
  height: 50px;
}
#left {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  background: red;
}
#right {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  background: blue;
}
#subDiv {
  background: green;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="left">
  </div>
  <div id="right">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="subDiv">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Clear divs of floats. Also, be careful that you have a typo in the CSS. "displayLinline-block".